# dynamic navbar offset().top number value not working

Tags: jquery, navbar, offset

I'm having a problem with `jquery.offset().top` and I can't figure it out.

In the code below navbarposition is a number, returns 160 but does not work in calc / if statement. If i replace variable navbarposition with 160 it does work. I need it to be dynamic tho.

I've tried `Math.round()`, `.toFixed(2)`, `IntParse()` to no avail. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/pzrcq2h7/

```js
var topposition = $(this).scrollTop();

var navbarposition = $('#shownavbarbg').offset().top; //160
var navbaroffset = 43; //position (160) + height of menu (43)

var calc = navbarposition + navbaroffset;

if (topposition > calc) {
  $('#navbarbg').show("slide", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 500);
} else {
  $('#navbarbg').hide("slide", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the html part and full script you wrote?

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri Sure, I made a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/pzrcq2h7/. Which seems interesting since it looks to be working properly in the fiddle. (It shows the #navbarbg on scroll with variable navbarposition in script.) I'll double-check. Only thing different in the fiddle is bootstrap i guess.

Comment: Now i got it to work with code: var navbarposition = $('#shownavbarbg').offset().top; except i can't add the navbaroffset variable to add height to it? Am I going crazy? How can't I add two numbers together?

Comment: update: Also i can subtract height/pixels, but i can't add? if (topposition >= navbarposition - 43) { does work, yet + 43 does not.

Comment: Yes it works fine in the fiddle. I can't understand the exact problem now.

Comment: Yeah i couldn't get it to work in my local files. Works fine in the fiddle. I ended up with a half-solution to just move the physical id to a div lower in the doc and subtracting height from it. (as i said, I couldn't add height so.) Kind of not a problem afterall I guess I created it myself. Was very odd tho.